# Is G will form a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given $G = \{f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ; f \text{continuous}\}$
with respect to the operation defined by $(f.g)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ for all $x \in [0, 1].$

My question is  that  Is  G  will  form a group ?

i know that $G$ will form  a ring  but im  not sure  about group ?

Comment: All rings are groups, it can't be a ring if it's not even a group.

Comment: Why do you think it's a ring?

Comment: @Henrik $(f + g)(x)= f(x)  +g(x)$  and $( f.g)(x) = f(x).g(x)$

Comment: Rings (typically) have *two* binary operations. (I can't think of any that don't; in fact, I think a consequence of requirement that $0\neq 1$ is that the two binary operations of a ring must be distinct.)

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg $\mathbb{R} $  is  a  commutative ring with unity

Comment: @Jasmine which is also a group, under addition of real numbers. I'd suggest you go back over the definition of a ring.

Comment: @jasmine: That's no argument, that it's a ring. And it seems you're mixing up your operations. A ring has *two* binary operations, and is a commutative group with respect to the first, so if your question should make any sense, the first one should be (pointwise) multiplication, and the second should be something that distributes over that, not (pointwise) addition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily, since it the elements may not have an inverse, consider the example

$$
f(x) = (x - 1/2)^2 ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ 0 \leq x \leq 1
$$

it does not have an inverse but $f \in G$. So the element $f^{-1}$ does not exist, and $G$ is not a group

Comment: The operation is pointwise multiplication (not composition).  So $f(x)=0$ would do.   All $f$ has to do is be zero somewhere., as $\frac1{f(x)}$ would have to be the inverse.

Comment: @ChrisCuster You're absolutely right, I overcomplicated the example. Thanks